# MySql query not returning correct data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, inner-join, where-clause, date-comparison

I have a Wordpress MySQL database that I need to create a custom query for using SQL. I am trying to return the current event (post) where the "date_start" value is less than the current day and the "date_end" value is greater than or equal to the current day. I know that there is a data record that should be returned butnothing is being returned when I try to do a search on both "date_start" and "date_end"

This is my old SQL statement:

```
select ID, post_name, meta_id, meta_key, meta_value from wp_posts inner join wp_postmeta on wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id and ((meta_key='date_end' and meta_value >= CURDATE() + interval 1 day) and (meta_key='date_start' and meta_value < CURDATE())) where post_type='programs' order by meta_value
```

The new SQL statement:

```
    SELECT
    ID,
    post_name,
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_start') AS 'date_start',
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_end') AS 'date_end'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE
    post_type = 'programs'
    AND ((CURDATE() >= (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_start'))
    AND (CURDATE() <= (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_end')))
ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`ID` ASC
```

And the date that is being returned is:

```
ID      post_name                   date_start  date_end
1221    culture-analytics           20160307    20160610
2446    culture-analytics-tutorials 20160308    20160311
```

I have also tried where the date_start and date_end portion of the inner join was in the WHERE clause.

IMPORTANT: wp_postmeta is a Many To 1 schema, whereas 'date_start' and 'date_end' are separate records but both point to the same PostID

What seems to be the problem.

Comment: `meta_value >= CURDATE() + interval 1 day` is not the same as "greater than or equal to the current day", it is "greater than or equal to tomorrow". Also, if the values are strings, you may need to do some type conversions to get expected/needed comparison results.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes I know about the greater than or equal to I understand that part. If I take out either the "date_start" part or the "date_end" part records are returned. but if I include both nothing is returned. So it does recognize and convert accordingly the date comparison

Comment: Change to OR before the second meta_key condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two conflicting constraints on meta_key. Your query expects meta_key to equal both "date_start" and "date_end" at the same time.

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    post_name,
    meta_id,
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_start') AS 'date_start',
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_end') AS 'date_end'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE
    post_type = 'programs'
    AND (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_start') < CURDATE()
    AND (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'date_end') >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY 4
```

I don't have access to a Wordpress database so I haven't run it but it might work...

Comment: thank you that did help a little bit, the only change I made was to put the CURDATE() before the "select" statements in the "WHERE" clause, however it is returning one more record than it should. The date_end for that extra record is 20160610

Comment: Can you post the actual query you're using the the data set that is returned?

Comment: Posted the your version and the dataset returned

Comment: Well CURDATE() <= "2016-06-10" would yield true... (today is "2016-03-11" and it's before "2016-06-10")

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that. I just now have to find a way to exclude that one.

Comment: Maybe describe the criteria you want and I'll try to help. By the way note that the query in Uueerdo's answer will have better performance...

Comment: there is another meta_key called "parent_code" which is blank for the one that I do not want to be returned, the event that I want returned DOES have a value in the meta_value for the meta_key="parent_code"

Comment: Well you can add something like this to the WHERE criteria: AND ((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = ID AND meta_key = 'parent_code') <> '') (or if by "blank" you mean "NULL" - change the " = ''" to " IS NOT NULL")

Comment: Ding ding, that was the icing on the cake. Thank you ALL for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@obe caught the core problem with your original query in his answer; but I would solve it with an additional join rather than four subqueries:

```
SELECT ID, post_name, meta_id
   , beginMeta.meta_key As beginKey, endMeta.meta_key AS endKey
   , beginMeta.meta_value AS beginDate
   , endMeta.meta_value AS endDate
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS endMeta 
   ON wp_posts.ID = endMeta.post_id 
   AND endMeta.meta_key='date_end' 
   AND endMeta.meta_value >= CURDATE() + interval 1 day 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS beginMeta 
   ON wp_posts.ID = beginMeta .post_id 
   AND beginMeta.meta_key='date_start' 
   AND beginMeta.meta_value < CURDATE() 
WHERE post_type='programs' 
ORDER BY beginDate, endDate
;
```

Edit: This assumes (post_id, meta_key) combinations are unique in wp_postmeta.

Comment: This would indeed perform better... just note that in the second query it should be "beginMeta.meta_key" and "beginMeta.meta_value", and also in the ORDER BY you have to explicitly write "beginMeta.meta_value" and "endMeta.meta_value"...

Comment: `ORDER BY` can use the aliases...oh, doh...and yeah, that second is a copy-paste goof. Fixing....

Comment: HAHA, I don't understand why that one extra record is showing up though., the one that ends on 20160610

Comment: @mattgcon As obe said in his comment chain, that date range satisfies your criteria.